# Dplyr commands within a function

Tags: r, class, dplyr, piping

I have a dataset and three functions.  The first function subject(x, n) has two arguments: an object x and a value n.  subject() converts x to a data.frame class and then applies dplyr functions on x using the piping operator %>%.
Then the object returned by subject(x, n) feeds the function visit(x, n) which is linked with subject(x, n) with the piping operator %>%.  The visit(x, n) function converts the class of the object it receives to a data.frame then applies the filter() function of dplyr on the dataframe and returns the resulting dataframe after it converts it to a "visit" class.  Last, a third function room(x, r) is linked with the pipe operator %>% with visit(x, n), applies a filter() on the object received, after it changes its class to dataframe and returns an object of class "room" The functions "visit" and "room" do not work as designed. I wonder if you could help me understand the error and its causes and suggest ways to fix the code.  Thank you.

```
       > y  
          id visit    room value timepoint
          1  14     0 bedroom  6.00        53
          2  15     0     den  6.00        54
          3  14     1     den  2.75        55
          4  14     0 bedroom  2.75        56
          5  17     1     den  2.75        57
          6  15     1 bedroom  2.75        58
          7  16     2     den  6.00        59
          8  16     2     den  6.00        60
          9  14     2     den  2.75        61
         10  12     0     den  2.75        62


      subject <- function(x, n){
                     class(x) <- "data.frame"
                     y <- x %>% select(id, visit, room, value) %>% filter(id == n)
                     structure(y, class = c("subject"))
                  }

          visit <- function(x, n){
                       class(x) <- "data.frame"
                       x %>% filter(visit == n)
                       structure(x, class = "visit")
                     }

          room <- function(x, r){
                       class(x) <- "data.frame"
                       x %>% filter(room == r)
                       structure(x, class = "room")
                   }

        w <- subject(y, 14) %>% visit(0) %>% room("bedroom")

        class(w) <- "data.frame"

        w 

          id visit    room value
        1 14     0 bedroom  6.00
        2 14     1     den  2.75
        3 14     0 bedroom  2.75
        4 14     2     den  2.75
```

Comment: Need to use `traceback()` to figure out which of this sequence of calls is calling `match` incorrectly. It would be ideal if you could post `dput(y)`.

Comment: `class = visit` or `class = "visit"` ?

Comment: You are right.  It is class = "visit"

Comment: Assigning `class(x) <- "data.frame"` doesn't do any *conversion*, it just calls something a data frame. You'd be safer using an actual conversion function like `as.data.frame`.

Comment: I tried to use as.data.frame(x) in conjunction with class(x) <- "data.frame" (otherwise I was getting an error message that the as.data.frame method could not be applied to an object of the class "subject").  Nevertheless, I got the same results as before, i.e. the visit() and room() functions did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be altered as follows:

```
        visit <- function(x, n){
                   class(x) <- "data.frame"
                   y <- x %>% filter(visit == n)
                   structure(y, class = "visit")
                 }

        room <- function(x, r){
                   class(x) <- "data.frame"
                   y <- x %>% filter(room == r)
                   structure(y, class = "room")
               }
```

After the edits the code worked without a problem